# TextCounter & Trigger innerHTML in two separate input areas

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn Javascript. I have two questions regarding TextCounter & Trigger innerHTML.

1. My code below, how to separately trigger innerHTML for two inputs?
2. Why the alert info which is "over!!" still shows while deleting the number of words in the textarea?

Can someone please help? Much appreciated!

***HTML***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
      <textarea name="line01" rows="3" style="width:340px;" 
onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.01,this.form.countDisplay01,10);" 
onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.01,this.form.countDisplay01,10);">
      </textarea>
      <br>
      <input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay01" width: 25px" 
value="10">characters remaining
      <p id="go1"></p> 
    </form>

    <form>
      <textarea name="line02" rows="3" style="width:340px;" 
onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.02,this.form.countDisplay02,8);" 
onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.02,this.form.countDisplay02,8);">
      </textarea>
      <br>
      <input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay02" width: 25px" 
value="8">characters remaining
      <p id="go2"></p> 
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

***Javascript***

```
<script> 
    function textCounter(textField, showCountField, maxAmount) {
        if (textField.value.length <= maxAmount) {
          showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("go1").innerHTML = "<span 
style='color:red'>Over!!</span>";
          document.getElementById("go2").innerHTML = "<span 
style='color:red'>Over!!</span>";
          textField.value = textField.value.substring(0,maxAmount);
        } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Text Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<textarea name="01" rows="3" style="width:340px;" 
onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form['01'],this.form.countDisplay01,10,1);" 
onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form['01'],this.form.countDisplay01,10,1);">
</textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay01" style="width: 25px;" value="28"> characters remaining
<p id="go1"></p> 
</form>

<form>
<textarea name="02" rows="3" style="width:340px;" 
onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form['02'],this.form.countDisplay02,8,2);" 
onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form['02'],this.form.countDisplay02,8,2);">
</textarea>
<br>
<input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay02" style="width: 25px" value="15">characters remaining
<p id="go2"></p> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script> 
function textCounter(textField, showCountField, maxAmount,id) {
    if (textField.value.length <= maxAmount) {
        showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
        document.getElementById('go'+id).innerHTML  = '';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('go'+id).innerHTML  = '<span style="color:red">Over!!</span>';
        textField.value = textField.value.substring(0,maxAmount);
    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for the help!! It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

As you have used a name that starts with number, it's not a valid variable. You should access it through dictionary lookup:

```
textCounter(this.form['01'],this.form.countDisplay01,10);
```

For the alert text, you should reset the `innerHTML` in the first `if` clause:

```
if (textField.value.length <= maxAmount) {
  showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
  document.getElementById("go1").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("go2").innerHTML = "";
} else {
  document.getElementById("go1").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Over!!</span>";
  document.getElementById("go2").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Over!!</span>";
  textField.value = textField.value.substring(0,maxAmount);
}
```

This will remove the alert text, on the next keypress. If you want to remove the text immediately, you have two options:

1. Forget about showing an error.
2. Show the error for about a fraction of second and then remove it. Using something like a `setTimeout`. But you should remember, the window won't redraw before returning from your function. So, setting the alert text first, and then removing it at the end of your function, will be the same as doing option 1.

Comment: Didn't realized I pasted a wrong name format here. awkward. Thank you so much for your help and explanation!!